# Is there an event hook in worker node fired after tests stoped?

Tags: python, locust

In my each worker, there are some global variables (worker level), and I want to reset them after tests stoped (or every time when tests will start), is there an event hook I can use?

Answer (score 0):

How about test_start / test_stop?

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop